# Continuity ( and differentiability) of a function specified by the functional equation $f\bigl(xf(y)\bigr)f(y)=f(x+y)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity, functional-equations

I was studying the functional equation $f\bigl(xf(y)\bigr)f(y)=f(x+y)$ and observed that for $x=\delta y$ we can write $f(y+\delta y)-f(y) = f(y)\Bigl(f\bigl(\delta yf(y)\bigr)-1\Bigr)$. I then reasoned that, as $f(0)=1$ we can make $f(y+\delta y)-f(y)$ arbitrarily small by decreasing $\delta y$ so the function ought to be continuous. I want to know whether this proves the function is continuous or the proof requires $f$ to be continuous at $x=0$ as well. Also what can I do to prove this (apart from solving the equation)?

The solution, by the way, is $f(x)= \frac{2}{2-x}$ for $x\ne2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [determining every function $f$ defined for positive numbers satisfying $f\big(xf(y)\big)f(y)=f(x+y)$, $f(2)=0$ and $f(x)\ne 0$ for $0\le x&lt;2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913593/determining-every-function-f-defined-for-positive-numbers-satisfying-f-bigxf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you're saying : 
 $f(y+\delta y)-f(y) = f(y)(f(\delta yf(y))-1) \implies \lim\limits_{\delta y \to 0} (f(y+\delta y)-f(y)) =  \lim\limits_{\delta y \to 0} f(y)(f(\delta yf(y))-1) = f(y)(f(0)-1) =0 $
For that to be true you would have to have $f(x)$ be continuous in $0$. If $f(x)$ is discontinuous in $0$ it would be discontinuous everywhere, that could be.
But if it's continuous in $0$ it would have to be continuous everywhere. But your solution is not continuous in $x=2$

Comment: Thanks, incidentally the original problem actually includes a few more conditions restricting the domain to real numbers < 2, so it all works out despite 2 not being in the domain of 2/(x-2). So is there no other way to prove continuity of the function?

Comment: @CompulsiveMathurbator Have you found your solution without assuming continuity? In that case the proof would be in there somewhere..

Comment: as a matter of fact yes, the same inequalities I used to solve it can prove continuity (redundant but possible). Thanks.